# 'builtin-baseline' in vcpkg for installing Franka Matlab?

Tags: vcpkg

I want to install the Matlab Extension from LibFranka according to

After installing Visual Studio, they state i should install vcpkg, add it to the PATH and run

*vcpkg install eigen3:x64-windows*

However, the error message

*error: this vcpkg instance requires a manifest with a specified baseline in order to interact with ports. Please add 'builtin-baseline' to the manifest or add a 'vcpkg-configuration.json' that redefines the default registry.*

is yielded. I looked the documentation of vcpkg, but I have no clue what to put in which json file.

I tried adding a vcpkg-configuration.json but this file was ignored. I read in a forum, that a vcpkg.json has to exist but I dont know what to fill in, otherwise it states "Unexpected EOF in vcpkg.json".

I read that vcpkg builtin-baseline are to specify versions, but I dont know what to put in. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this recently with an existing cmake project that had a `vcpkg.json` manifest file. Previously, I had been using the [getting started](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) instructions, until I saw that Visual Studio had listed vcpkg as an installation option (so I thought I'd used the built-in vcpkg).

Trying to find more, there was a comment in the [versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/versioning#example) that mentioned running:

```
vcpkg x-update-baseline --add-initial-baseline
```

It appears to be [an experimental command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/commands/update-baseline#add-initial-baseline). It updated the vcpkg.json to have the `builtin-baseline` entry.

Other options appeared to be grabbing a commit hash value from [the vcpkg commit history](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/commits/master).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the vcpkg supplied with VS in the recommended manifest mode, if you're just using vcpkg packages (rather than creating one), from a VS command prompt you can use:

```
vcpkg new --application
```

This will create 2 json files that should get you going.