# What is baseline in vcpkg?

Tags: c++, vcpkg

When writing vcpkg.json for a top-level project, I got the following error:

```
error: this vcpkg instance requires a manifest with a specified baseline in order to interact with ports. Please add 'builtin-baseline' to the manifest or add a 'vcpkg-configuration.json' that redefines the default registry.
```

What does baseline mean? I tried looking up the docs, and apparently it refers to a Git repo hash and is used for versioning, but what exactly does this mean? Wasn't able to find any details about this.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184879/builtin-baseline-in-vcpkg-for-installing-franka-matlab should help to get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From versioning [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/versioning#baselines):

> Baselines define a global version floor for what versions will be considered.

It's really nothing more than a git commit hash in a git registry (builtin registry aka vcpkg git repository is itself a git registry). Vcpkg uses it to extract version information for a port from `baseline.json`.

For example, if we wanted to install `qtbase`:

- with baseline `4bee3f5aae7aefbc129ca81c33d6a062b02fcf3b` vcpkg would look at [baseline.json@4bee3f5aae7aefbc129ca81c33d6a062b02fcf3b](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/4bee3f5aae7aefbc129ca81c33d6a062b02fcf3b/versions/baseline.json) and find `qtbase@6.6.1#10`.
- with baseline `11afcc7e8b7118f3a0ae97140ce8037b7f53ad64` vcpkg would look at [baseline.json@11afcc7e8b7118f3a0ae97140ce8037b7f53ad64](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/11afcc7e8b7118f3a0ae97140ce8037b7f53ad64/versions/baseline.json) and find
  `qtbase@6.3.2#3`.